# WordPress: Click a menu item, but jump to http://iyfsearch.com/

Tags: wordpress, cron

It is very weird that when I click a menu item on my WordPress site, it **additionally** opens up a new tab loading a new page where its url is something like `http://iyfsearch.com/?dn=jboxcdn.com&pid=9PO755G95`.

The `/var/log/syslog` is filled with `CRON[***]`,

```
$ tail /var/log/syslog
Aug 28 19:57:01 localhost CRON[27038]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug 28 19:58:01 localhost CRON[27048]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/tobediff.com/r8dyK5  > /dev/null 2>&1)
Aug 28 19:58:01 localhost CRON[27049]: (www-data) CMD (/1.sh)
Aug 28 19:58:01 localhost CRON[27046]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug 28 19:59:01 localhost CRON[27057]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/tobediff.com/r8dyK5  > /dev/null 2>&1)
Aug 28 19:59:01 localhost CRON[27058]: (www-data) CMD (/1.sh)
Aug 28 19:59:01 localhost CRON[27055]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug 28 20:00:01 localhost CRON[27064]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/tobediff.com/r8dyK5  > /dev/null 2>&1)
Aug 28 20:00:01 localhost CRON[27065]: (www-data) CMD (/1.sh)
Aug 28 20:00:01 localhost CRON[27062]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

What are the possible reasons? How do I fix this issue?

Comment: i suspect your site is hacked

Comment: Definitely sounds like a hack. Ideally, hire a professional to clean the site. At minimum, try a security plugin or two and contact your host to see if you can isolate it, and if you can restore a backup before the site was hacked and then change all the passwords, that would be safest.

Comment: It is not unusual for the syslog to have entries from cron in it.   If you don't recognize the jobs being run however, maybe they were installed as part of the hack.

Comment: See also: [IYFsearch hack | WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/iyfsearch-hack/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your .htaccess for any unknown entries, check that file permissions are 664 and folders are 755, and check your web folder/folders listed for any unknown files and remove them:

```
var/www/tobediff.com/r8dyK5
/1.sh
```

WP Permissions: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/

Also maybe add a security plugin like iThemes that has file change detection that will alert you if a file gets put on your site that you did not add yourself.

Worse case, nuke and rebuild...